# Add Custom Button in Edit Form

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have added a custom button in my jqGrid Edit form, created using **beforeShowForm** event. Onclick of custom button i want to perform ***ADD*** operation. 
below are my code ..

```
 beforeShowForm: function(form) { 
          //Create Custom ADD Button
          $('<a href="#">Add<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-disk"></span></a>')
            .click(function() {
                var $self = $(this);
               $self.jqGrid("editGridRow", $self.jqGrid("getGridParam", "selrow"),
                {
                  editData: {//Function to Add parameters to the status 
                    oper: 'add', //trying to pass parameter to server
                  },
                });
            }).addClass("fm-button ui-state-default ui-corner-all fm-button-icon-left")
              .prependTo("#Act_Buttons>td.EditButton");
```

the Code
 `editData: {//Function to Add parameters to the status 
                        oper: 'add', //trying to pass parameter to server
                      },`

shows **TypeError: a(...)[0].p is undefined**  error . Any idea how to achieve this??

[image: Add Button]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main error in your code is the place where you use `this`. Inside of `beforeShowForm` is `this` initialized to the DOM of the grid, but inside of `click` event handler to `$('<a href="#">Add<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-disk"></span></a>')` it's initialized to `<a>` element. So you get the error "TypeError: a(...)[0].p is undefined". To fix the code you need just **move initializing of `$this` variable in the outer callback function `beforeShowForm`**:

```
beforeShowForm: function(form) { 
    var $self = $(this); // !!! place it here !!!

    //Create Custom ADD Button
    $('<a href="#">Add<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-disk"></span></a>')
        .click(function() {
            $self.jqGrid("editGridRow", $self.jqGrid("getGridParam", "selrow"), {
                editData: {//Function to Add parameters to the status 
                    oper: 'add', //trying to pass parameter to server
                },
            });
        }).addClass("fm-button ui-state-default ui-corner-all fm-button-icon-left")
          .prependTo("#Act_Buttons>td.EditButton");
}
```

Comment: thanks. you are right.  But its not getting Posted to the server. I guess I dont need to pass url here. Any ideas ??

Comment: @Wahab: You are welcome! Posting to the server depend on *other options* which you use in jqGrid. Do you set for example `editurl`? Alternatively you can use `url` directly: `$self.jqGrid("editGridRow", $self.jqGrid("getGridParam", "selrow"), { url: "yourServerUrl", editData: {... }});`

Comment: i use editurl. i want to achieve 'add' operation inside edit form. for this do i need new url or can i use the editurl with oper:add??

Comment: @Wahab: I don't full understand what you do and why you need **additional** Add button. So I just tried to fix the error `"TypeError: a(...)[0].p is undefined"`. The standard way is usage of `"new"` parameter as rowid (see [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#adding_row)). I don't understand which sense could have calling `editGridRow` when one have already have Add/Edit  opened. What you need to do? Probably you need just have some logic in `onclickSubmit` callback?

Comment: What i have is a Basic Add/Edit/Delete Function. First i have a Normal Add Form.  In the Edit Form i want Both Add and Edit Operation to be performed so that user while selecting a row for editing from grid they can either **add** or **edit**. This is useful when user want to add different **color** for the same name, width and substance.